# if is_page() is not working with wp_redirect

Tags: pages, wp-redirect, cookies

I have a plugin installed, which is creating user profiles on frontend. The ID of this page is 301 in backend of wordpress. If a profile site is visited, i want to append the url with a parameter. The parameter value is stored in a cookie.
The code for appending the URL is working, but when i add the code to only show on this page id its not working.

The code is executed in my child themes functions.php

**NOT WORKING**

```
if( is_page(301)) {
    echo 'page';

// Event ID in der URL als $_GET hinzufügen
function lwb_param_redirect(){
    if( isset( $_COOKIE['lwb_event_id'] ) and !$_GET['event_id'] ) {
        $location = esc_url( add_query_arg( 'event_id', $_COOKIE['lwb_event_id'] ));
        wp_redirect( $location );
    }
}
    add_action( 'template_redirect', 'lwb_param_redirect' );
}
```

**WORKING**

```
// Event ID in der URL als $_GET hinzufügen
function lwb_param_redirect(){
    if( isset( $_COOKIE['lwb_event_id'] ) and !$_GET['event_id'] ) {
        $location = esc_url( add_query_arg( 'event_id', $_COOKIE['lwb_event_id'] ));
        wp_redirect( $location );
    }
}
    add_action( 'template_redirect', 'lwb_param_redirect' );
```

The working example appends the URL parameter global to all my sites, this i what i want to prevent, because the event_id is only needed on the profile pages.

Comment: Where is the code in your question? Is it on a page template? A shortcode? What's the problem you're trying to solve with this?Surely if you're inside `templates/profile.php` then the answer is always going to be `ja`?

Comment: the code is in functions.php and will be executed on every page! I want to filter only the profile pages, and add some code there!

Comment: And how are you loading the template for the profile?

Comment: the themplate file is loaded in the plugin. I dont know when this is executed...

Comment: i will edit my question

Comment: Couldn't you use the same check that you use in `template_redirect`?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a plugin template, you might find the slug is more reliable for a condition - see below for alternate approach.

When using `is_page_template()` the parameter passed is `anypath/filename.php`.  Without knowing your file system specifics or the name of the plugin, it is impossible to give you the correct relative path for this.  Use `plugin_dir_path()` to get the plugin root, then subfolder, etc for this approach.

**Alternate Approach**

Or go with `get_page_template_slug()` to eliminate the need to know the template location as it only returns the page template filename.

```
$template = get_page_template_slug(); // You may need to pass the post ID depending on context

if ( 'profile.php' === $template ) {
    echo 'yes';
} else {
    echo 'no';
}
```

WP Codex for more info: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_template_slug/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/

Comment: No longer applicable after rewritten question